# Different headers in different views (Blade template, Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I use the Bladetemplate of Laravel. Is there a way to set different header for different views with only one include in master.blade.php?

**master.blade.php**

```
@include("elements.header")
  @yield('content')
  @section("footer")
  @show
```

**view.blade.php**

```
@extends("layouts.master")
    @section("title")

    @stop
    @section("content")
  @include("elements.error")

  @section("footer")
  @include("elements.footer")
  @stop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include different header templates for different views, there is **no need** to include anything from your layout. Instead, **include the proper header template into a separate section in your views** and then **display that section in the master template**:

**master.blade.php**

```
@yield('header')
@yield('content')
```

**viewA.blade.php**

```
@extends("layouts.master")

@section('header')
  @include('headerA')
@stop

@section('content')
  view content
@stop
```

**viewB.blade.php**

```
@extends("layouts.master")

@section('header')
  @include('headerB')
@stop

@section('content')
  view content
@stop
```

This way, each of your views includes different header templates into the **header** section that will be later displayed in master layout with **@yield('header')**.

Answer (score 0):

In your main layout

```
<title>@yield('title','Home')</title>
```

Then In your views Just call

```
@section('title','My View 1')

@section('title','My View 2')
```

The second parameter in yield is the default if none defined.